# Test project does not open in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I try and open the test project in visual studio 2010 I get an error saying the template is not found.

Does anyone know of a way to manually install this template or repair it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "the test project"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Visual Studio installer any time to repair your VS installation or to add/remove features.
Probably your installation is missing the examples...